# PHP Session - Redirect URL issue through Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, session, session-cookies

I've made a JS script on our Wordpress site that basically reads the cookies and based on that shows logged in/out state elements, which works fine.

My issue is that I am asked to redirect the user to a deposit cashier pages through session once the user is logged in and hits deposit. So I've considered to run the following PHP code through functions.php

```
<?php 
  add_action('wp_head', 'set_session_deposits', 1);
  function set_session_deposits(){
    if ( is_page( 6386 ) ) {
      session_start();
      if(isset($_COOKIE['username'])){ //logged in
        $userCashier = $_POST['username']; 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $userCashier;
        echo $_SESSION['username']; // This shows me the result perfectly
        if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username'])){
          header('location:cashier.php username='.$_SESSION['username'].'');
        }
        else{
          echo "SESSION user isn't set."; // This is the result I get from the isset()
        }
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

page id 6386 is the Deposit page on wordpress site that, once user enters, he gets redirected to url of cashier where cashier side knows the username value.

I've tried this code but it doesn't seem to work and am out of ideas, if you can help would be grateful.

Comment: Some questions that may help people give you an answer ... What happens when you run the code? Do you get an error, or it just doesn't redirect? Adding some echo statements can help you see where it's failing (ex, does it get to the session_start line, if so does it get to the header line?) Why is there a space after cashier.php in the header line, shouldn't that be a question mark?